# how to protect a method from parallel access with synchronization(){} block in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

I have the following activity :

```
public class FaceActivity extends BiometricActivity implements CameraControlsListener
```

The onCreate method of this activity is as follows :

```
controlsView = new CameraControlsView(this, this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            controlsView.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(controlsView);
```

The CameraControlsView class is as follows :

```
public class CameraControlsView extends LinearLayout {

    // ===========================================================
    // Public types
    // ===========================================================

    public interface CameraControlsListener {
        void onSwitchCamera();

        void onChangeFormat();
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Private fields
    // ===========================================================

    private CameraControlsListener mListener;

    // ===========================================================
    // Public constructor
    // ===========================================================

    public CameraControlsView(Context context, CameraControlsListener listener) {
        super(context);
        if (listener == null) throw new NullPointerException("listener");
        mListener = listener;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_controls, this, true);
        ImageView switchCamera = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_camera);
        switchCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    mListener.onSwitchCamera();
                }
            }
        });

        ImageView changeFormat = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.change_format);
        changeFormat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onChangeFormat();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The onSwitchCamera function is overrided in FaceAcivity which is as follows :

```
@Override
    public void onSwitchCamera() {
        if (!FacePreferences.isUseLiveness(this)) {
            cancel();
            NCamera currentCamera = client.getFaceCaptureDevice();
            for (NDevice device : client.getDeviceManager().getDevices()) {
                if (device.getDeviceType().contains(NDeviceType.CAMERA)) {
                    if (!device.equals(currentCamera)) {
                        client.setFaceCaptureDevice((NCamera) device);
                        startCapturing();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

When I press switchCamera button onSwitchCamera function is called . When I click it more than once, not waiting for camera to change and start capturing, there might be some racing condition happening and then somehow camera output is not shown. So I want to protect that method from parallel access  with synchronization(){} block .

I have kept syncronized keyword in the onClick method of switchCamera button but it is not working . How can I protect a method from parallel access ?

Comment: Why not use a boolean to wait for the first operation to finish if you don't need concurrency?

Comment: Can you not disable the `switchCamera button` so that it can not be pressed more than once?

Comment: I want to protect a method from parallel access with synchronization(){} block

Comment: Then why don't you simply synchronize the method like so `public synchronized void onSwitchCamera() {    }`.

Comment: synchronize block or method will block the UI thread. Hence not recommended for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

General speaking you should check the camera callbacks: with that camera callbacks (onActive, onClosed) you will know when it makes sense to enable the button or not.

The way you tried to use `synchronized` does not really make sense since you need synchronization, but **not** in that meaning of accessing the same "software" object to the same time from different threads. You need to synchronize with the camera driver.

I mean it does not make sense to enable the camera twice, just wait until it is done and offer then the option to disable it again.

Search for your `createCaptureSession()` call and add handle the enable state of the button in the `CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to remark, that any "synchronized" block affects performance, because of takes time itself, and locks other threads from accessing the scope of code. Besides, "synchronized" block caused lock on object instance which are in braces. "synchronized(this)" is a bad patters, because locks the whole instance."Synchronized" block is done to control access to resources, which can be accessed by threads concurrently and must provide isolation of their change. 
So  your

```
synchronized (this) {
    mListener.onSwitchCamera();                
}
```

seems out of reason, twice, when taking in consideration that it is injected in constructor and not changed. First - synchronized (this) basically does not prevent access to the listener from anyone else: "this" in your case- is an instance of inline (lambda) class, which is not accessible by others, except to event source (your OS, like I see, is Android, where any layout is working in UI thread). 
Second- you try synchronize access to instance which is not changeable only to call  its function(????). Nothing race condition can occur, because functions are bound to class before its instance initialization. If you want to synchronize access to Listener's resources, then you must doing it in the instance of the class, in the same void onSwitchCamera(). Like this, for example

```
 @Override
 public void onSwitchCamera() 
 {
     if (!FacePreferences.isUseLiveness(this)) {
         cancel();
         synchronized(client)
         {
             NCamera currentCamera = client.getFaceCaptureDevice();
             for (NDevice device : client.getDeviceManager().getDevices()) {
                 if (device.getDeviceType().contains(NDeviceType.CAMERA)) {
                     if (!device.equals(currentCamera)) {
                         client.setFaceCaptureDevice((NCamera) device);
                         startCapturing();
                         break;
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

But you must lock only instance, which are in danger of race condition and only for time of the danger exists.